# Override Number.toLocaleString("fa-IR") and change its thousands separator character for Persian numbers

Tags: javascript, localization, number-formatting, farsi

I need to reformat numeric values based on the locale format, and to do this I use `Number.toLocaleString("LOCAL")` function. In Iran, the majority of people prefer to use `,` as a thousands separator character, but `Number.toLocaleString("fa-IR")` uses `٬` (Technically٬ it is correct).

Although you can replace the character by using the following code, is there any way to **override** the `Number.toLocaleString("fa-IR")`'s functionality?

```js
function formatNumber(number) {
  let string = number.toLocaleString('fa-IR'); // ۱۲٬۳۴۵٫۶۷۹
  number = number.replace(/\٬/g, ",‬");
  return string;
}
    
formatNumber(12345.6789); // the result: ۱۲,۳۴۵٫۶۷۹
```

PS: I know there are plenty of similar code-snippets out there, but I would like to override the built-in function (if possible).

Comment: I don't know whether the "majority" of people prefer to use `,` (Lating comma) or not but this is wrong.
Even if they do, they may like a thousands separator that **looks like a Latin comma** not the actual Latin comma.
You should not use a non-standard character.
If you like a thousands separator to look like a Latin comma, change your font.
There are free fonts like [*Vazir*](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-font) and commercial fonts like *IranSansX*
that have their separator look like a Latin comma.

Comment: Please see [this Wikipedia article](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7_%DA%A9%D9%86%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87%E2%80%8C%DB%8C_%D9%87%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%86).

Comment: [This sentence from a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#:~:text=To%20separate%20sequences%20of%20three%20digits%2C%20an%20Arabic%20thousands%20separator%20(rendered%20as%3A%20%D9%AC)%2C%20a%20Latin%20comma%2C%20or%20a%20blank%20space%20may%20be%20used%3B%20however%20this%20is%20not%20a%20standard.%5B46%5D%5B47%5D%5B48%5D%20Example%3A%20%DB%B9%D9%AC%DB%B9%DB%B9%DB%B9%D9%AB%DB%B9%DB%B9%20(9%2C999.99)) says that using Latin comma or Blank space is not standard for Persian numbers (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: @Mahozad Yes you have understand it correctly and mentioned the correct points, but it was the customer preference. So it is out my control whether it is acceptable or not. And about changing the font, it is not my desire because in that case I have to add a new dependency (font file) and increase the traffic network.

Comment: OK, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to change the prototype of `Number`, then yes. It is often warned against changing the prototype of a built in class, as that could mess with other libraries and such.

Forging ahead regardless:

```js
const old = Number.prototype.toLocaleString;
Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function(locale)
{
  let result = old.call(this, locale);
  if(locale === 'fa-IR')
  {
    result = result.replace(/\٬/g, ",‬");
  }
  return result;
}
```